Error loading rule @typescript-eslint/no-implied-eval lint-staged eslint --fix
I can not run eslint --fix with lint-staged
I'm trying to implement lint-staged husky. I already installed husky, lint-staged and relate packges.
 "scripts": {
    "dev": "next dev",
    "build": "next build",
    "start": "next start",
    "lint": "eslint src --ext .js,.jsx,.ts,.tsx",
    "format": "prettier --write \"src/**/*.{js,jsx,ts,tsx}\"",
    "pre-commit": "npm run lint",
    "lint-staged": "lint-staged",
    "lint-staged:debug": "lint-staged --debug",
    "prepare": "husky install"
  },
  "lint-staged": {
    "*.{html, css, tsx, jsx, ts, js, md, json}": "prettier --write",
    "*.{js, jsx, tsx, ts}": [
      "prettier --write",
      "eslint --fix"
    ]
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "babel-eslint": "10.x",
    "dotenv": "^16.4.5",
    "emailjs-com": "^3.2.0",
    "eslint-config-airbnb": "19.x",
    "eslint-config-airbnb-typescript": "17.x",
    "eslint-config-prettier": "8.x",
    "eslint-config-react": "1.x",
    "eslint-plugin-import": "2.x",
    "eslint-plugin-jsx-a11y": "6.x",
    "eslint-plugin-prettier": "5.x",
    "eslint-plugin-react": "7.x",
    "eslint-plugin-react-hooks": "4.x",
    "eslint-plugin-testing-library": "5.x",
    "next": "14.2.2",
    "next-themes": "^0.3.0",
    "react": "^18",
    "react-dom": "^18",
    "react-icons": "^5.1.0",
    "react-toastify": "^10.0.5"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@dwarvesf/react-eslint-config": "^1.0.1",
    "@next/eslint-plugin-next": "^13.5.3",
    "@types/node": "^20",
    "@types/react": "^18",
    "@types/react-dom": "^18",
    "@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin": "^7.16.0",
    "@typescript-eslint/parser": "^7.16.0",
    "autoprefixer": "^10.4.19",
    "eslint": "^8.50.0",
    "eslint-config-next": "^13.5.3",
    "husky": "^9.0.11",
    "lint-staged": "^15.2.7",
    "postcss": "^8",
    "prettier": "^3.3.2",
    "tailwindcss": "^3.4.3",
    "typescript": "^5.5.3"
  },

I followed some guide and update .eslintrc.js
 ignorePatterns: ['node_modules/', "babel.config.js"],
  env: {
    es6: true,
    browser: true,
    node: true,
  },
  globals: {
    io: true,
    chrome: true,
  }, 
  parser: '@typescript-eslint/parser',
  parserOptions: {
    ecmaVersion: 10,
    ecmaFeatures: {
      jsx: true,
    },
    project: './tsconfig.json',
    tsconfigRootDir: __dirname,
    createDefaultProgram: true,
    sourceType: 'module',
    babelOptions: {
      presets: [require.resolve('next/babel')],
    },
  },
  plugins: ['@typescript-eslint'],
  rules: {
    '@typescript-eslint/no-implied-eval': 'error',
  },

and tsconfig.json
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "ES6",
    "lib": ["dom", "dom.iterable", "esnext"],
    "allowJs": true,
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "strict": true,
    "noEmit": true,
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "module": "esnext",
    "moduleResolution": "bundler",
    "resolveJsonModule": true,
    "isolatedModules": true,
    "jsx": "preserve",
    "incremental": true,
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
    "types": ["node"],
    "noUnusedLocals": false,
    "noUnusedParameters": true,
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
    "noImplicitAny": true,
    "checkJs": false,
    "strictNullChecks": true,
    "strictFunctionTypes": true,
    "strictPropertyInitialization": true,
    "useUnknownInCatchVariables": false,
    "noImplicitThis": true,
    "plugins": [
      {
        "name": "next"
      }
    ]
  },
  "include": [
    "next-env.d.ts",
    ".next/types/**/*.ts",
    "**/*.ts",
    "**/*.tsx",
    "**/*.d.ts",
    "**/*.js",
    "**/*.jsx",
    "**/*.config.js",
    "src/**/*"
  ],
  "exclude": ["node_modules", "**/*.spec.ts"]
}

but still got error

I think the issue might be version of some package in package.json but I'm not sure. Does anyone know about this?
